# accessing package info from Activity constructor

Tags: android

I have a blank **final** field in my **Activity**.
 The value is not known at compile time and must be initialized from within the constructor.

To initialize the field, I access **getPackageName()** from within the constructor. Unfortunatelely this results in a **NullPointerException**.

Is there any means of accessing the package name or other Manifest info from within the constructor ?

```
private String packageName;
final private boolean proVersion;

// Constructor: for initialization of blank final variables
public myActivity() {
    packageName = getPackageName().toLowerCase();
    proVersion = appVersion();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it has to be "final"?

If not, you could call getPackageName() and get the value in onCreate() but not the constructor.

If it has to be final, you may have to assign the value by hard code;

Comment: final fields cannot be initialized in onCreate(). onCreate() is called after the constructor, which is too late and results in an error.

Comment: I prefer it to be final so that dead code is known at compile time and removed altogether from the apk.